# Characterization of linear functions in $\mathbb{R}$ using distance

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

First of all, by a linear function in $\mathbb{R}$, I mean a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of the form $f(x)=ax+b\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ ([not in the linear algebraic-sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_polynomial_function)). The question that I want some help with is in the end of this text (if you do not want to read all of it).

There are many characterizations of linear functions in $\mathbb{R}$ using distance. I believe those are the most common ones:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The following statements are equivalent:
>   - f is linear;
>   - For every $a<b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the length of the curve $\left\{(x,f(x)):a\leq x\leq b\right\}$ is the infimum of the lengths of (rectifiable) curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ conencting $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$;
>   -f is an isometry.
>   -There exists $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $a\neq b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $\left|\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\right|=k$.

The last condition says that linear functions are the ones that "maintain the variation globally". We could try to characterize linear function as the ones that "maintain the variation locally (in an uniform way)". To summarize:

> **Question**: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following: $$\forall r\in\mathbb{R},\ \exists g(r)\in\mathbb{R}\ \text{such that}\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ |f(x+r)-f(x)|=g(r).$$
>   Is $f$ necessarily linear?

The answer to this question is *no*. If $\mathcal{B}=\left\{b_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rationals, then we can define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function given in the basis as $f(b_i)=b_i^{-1}$. Then $f$ satisfies the condition above, with $g=|f|$. If we suppose that $\mathcal{B}$ contains $\pi,\pi^{-1},\pi^{-2},\ldots$ (which are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, since $\pi$ is transcedental), then $\lim f(\pi^{-n})=\lim \pi^n=\infty\neq f(0)$, so $f$ is not continuous, hence not linear.

However, in order to garantee the validity of the result, I tried assuming the $g$ is continuous, but I could not reach a solution (or counter-example).

> **Question**: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following: $$\forall r\in\mathbb{R},\ \exists g(r)\in\mathbb{R}\ \text{such that}\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ |f(x+r)-f(x)|=g(r).$$
>   Also, suppose that $g:r\mapsto g(r)$ is continuous. Is $f$ linear?

What we can show is that, given $p\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $g(2p)=0$ or $g(2p)=2g(p)$. Also, if $g(p)\neq 0$ then $g(p/n)=g(p)/n$ for every $n\in\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$. Also, $g(-r)=g(r)$ $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}$, but that is all I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=g^{-1}(0)$. Since $g(2p)\in\{0,2g(p)\}$ we have
$$ x\in S\implies 2x\in S.$$
Extending your result about $g(2p)$, note that $g(3p)=|g(2)\pm g(p)|$. Hence $g(3p)\in\{g(p),3g(p)\}$ and
$$ x\in S\iff 3x\in S.$$

Thus if $x\in S\setminus\{0\}$, then $\frac{2^k}{3^n}x\in S$ for all $n,k\in\mathbb N_0$.
The set of these numbers is dense in $\mathbb R_{>0}$ so that $g$ is identically $0$ and $f$ is constant (hence affine linear).

Therefore we may assume that $S\subseteq\{0\}$. Then $g(2p)=2g(p)$ for all $p$.
Let $p\ne0$. Then we have $f(p+x)-f(x)=a(x)g(p)$ for some $a(x)\in\{-1,1\}$, $f(x+2p)-f(x)=b(x)g(2p)=2b(x)g(p)$ for some $b(x)\in\{-1,1\}$. Then 
$$2b(x)=\frac{f(2p+x)-f(x)}{g(p)}=\frac{f(2p+x)-f(p+x)}{g(p)}+\frac{f(p+x)-f(x)}{g(p)}=a(x+p)+a(x)$$
is only possible with $a(x)=a(x+p)=b(x)$. Then by induction $a(x+np)=a(x)$ and hence $g(np)=ng(p)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. By going both ways, $g(\frac nmp)=\frac nmg(p)$ for all $\frac nm\in\mathbb Q_{>0}$ and ultimately $$g(x)=|x|\cdot g(1)\qquad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R.$$

Subtracting a constant from $f$ does not affect $g$ at all, multiplying with a constant just multiplies $g$ with the absolute value of that constant.
Therefore we may assume wlog. that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.
Then for $x\in \mathbb R$ we have 
$$f(x)\in \{-x,x\}$$
and also
$$ f(x)\in\{f(1)+(x-1),f(1)-(x-1)\}=\{x,2-x\}.$$
The only way to have $f(x)\ne x$ for some $x$ is therefore $f(x)=-x=2-x$, which is impossible.